# Как задать игроку силу движения в направление по углу его поворота?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Как зная угол поворота (Transform.Rotation.z) в 2D игре, задать силу движения (AddForce) по направлению куда смотрит игрок? Подразумевается что при нажатии на клавишу (к примеру пробел) корабль будет двигаться туда куда смотрит.
Поворот игрока осуществляется путем изменения поворота по Z (клавиши влево-право).

[image: скрин с юнити]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вектор, выпущенный по ходу движения корабля (куда корабль повернулся) переводите из локальных координат в мировые посредством [Transform.TransformDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) и по полученному вектору [прикладываете силу](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) в нужном вам [режиме](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html).

```
    Transform shipTransform;
    Vector3 direction;
    Rigidbody shipRb;
.....
        direction = shipTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        shipRb.AddForce(direction, ForceMode.Force);
```

Comment: почему то ваше решение не работает. в direction записывается вектор (0,0,1) при любом повороте. а сила не прикладывается вообще.

Comment: Без кода тяжело найти в чем проблема. А вы задали shipTransform и shipRb ?

Comment: да, конечно задал. собственно на скриншоте видно, просто shipTransform и shipRb обозначены как Player и Rigidbody

Comment: попробуйте вместо Vector3.forward использовать вектор с другим направлением (Vector3.Up или Vector3.right), возможно "вперед" у объекта не совпадает с направлением "носа корабля" и направление силы прикладывается перпендикулярно рабочей 2D плоскости.

Answer (score 1):

решение нашлось. 
получаем в риджидбоди угол, переводим в радианы. потом даем силу в направлении которое считаем через синус-косинус. (число 5 и -5 взято на рандомно,можно любое)

```
        float angel = rigidbody.rotation * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(5 * Mathf.Sin(angel), -5 * Mathf.Cos(angel), 0), ForceMode2D.Force);
```